# Import trained SVM from scikit-learn to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

I'm porting an algorithm that uses a Support Vector Machine from Python (using scikit-learn) to C++ (using the machine learning library of OpenCV).

I have access to the trained SVM in Python, and I can import SVM model parameters from an XML file into OpenCV. Since the SVM implementation of both scikit-learn and OpenCV is based on LibSVM, I think it should be possible to use the parameters of the trained scikit SVM in OpenCV.

The example below shows an XML file which can be used to initialize an SVM in OpenCV:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<my_svm type_id="opencv-ml-svm">
  <svm_type>C_SVC</svm_type>
  <kernel><type>RBF</type>
    <gamma>0.058823529411764705</gamma></kernel>
  <C>100</C>
  <term_criteria><epsilon>0.0</epsilon>
    <iterations>1000</iterations></term_criteria>
  <var_all>17</var_all>
  <var_count>17</var_count>
  <class_count>2</class_count>
  <class_labels type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>1</rows>
    <cols>2</cols>
    <dt>i</dt>
    <data>
      0 1</data></class_labels>
  <sv_total>20</sv_total>
  <support_vectors>
    <_>
      2.562423055146794554e-02 1.195797425735170838e-01
      8.541410183822648050e-02 9.395551202204914520e-02
      1.622867934926303379e-01 3.074907666176152077e-01
      4.099876888234874062e-01 4.697775601102455179e-01
      3.074907666176152077e-01 3.416564073529061440e-01
      5.124846110293592716e-01 5.039432008455355660e-01
      5.466502517646497639e-01 1.494746782168964394e+00
      4.168208169705446942e+00 7.214937388193202183e-01
      7.400275229357797802e-01</_>
    <!-- omit 19 vectors to keep it short -->
  </support_vectors>
  <decision_functions>
    <_>
      <sv_count>20</sv_count>
      <rho>-5.137523249549433402e+00</rho>
      <alpha>
        2.668992955678978518e+01 7.079767098112181145e+01
        3.554240018130368384e+01 4.787014908624512088e+01
        1.308470223155845069e+01 5.499185410034550614e+01
        4.160483074010306126e+01 2.885504210853826379e+01
        7.816431542954153144e+01 6.882061506693679576e+01
        1.069534676985309574e+01 -1.000000000000000000e+02
        -5.088050252552544350e+01 -1.101740897543916375e+01
        -7.519686789702373630e+01 -3.893481464245511603e+01
        -9.497774056452135483e+01 -4.688632332663718927e+00
        -1.972745089701982835e+01 -8.169343841768861125e+01</alpha>
      <index>
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
        </index></_></decision_functions></my_svm>
</opencv_storage>
```

I would now like to fill this XML file with values from the trained scikit-learn SVM. But I'm not sure how the parameters of scikit-learn and OpenCV correspond. Here is what I have so far (`clf` is the classifier object in Python):

- `<kernel><gamma>` corresponds to `clf.gamma`
- `<C>` corresponds to `clf.C`
- `<term_criteria><epsilon>` corresponds to `clf.tol`
- `<support_vectors>` corresponds to `clf.support_vectors_`

Is this correct so far? Now here are the items I'm not really sure:

- What about `<term_criteria><iterations>`?
- Does `<decision_functions><_><rho>` correspond to `clf.intercept_`?
- Does `<decision_functions><_><alpha>` correspond to `clf.dual_coef_`? Here I'm not sure because the scikit-learn documentation says "`dual_coef_` which holds the product y<sub>i</sub>α<sub>i</sub>". It looks like OpenCV expects only α<sub>i</sub>, and not y<sub>i</sub>α<sub>i</sub>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `epsilon` and `iterations` anymore, those are used in the training optimization problem. You can set them to your favorite number or ignore them.

Porting the support vectors may require some fiddling, as indexing may be different between [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) and [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv). The XML in your example has no sparse format for example.

As for the other parameters:

- `rho` should correspond to `intercept_`, but you may need to change sign.
- scikit's `dual_coef_` corresponds to `sv_coef` in standard [libsvm](/questions/tagged/libsvm) models (which is alpha_i*y_i).

If [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) complains about the values you provide for `alpha` when porting, use absolute values of [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn)'s `dual_coef_` (e.g. all positive). These are the true alpha values of an SVM model.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I haven't tried it yet, but anyway your answer contains some very useful information. How can I find out if I need to change the sign of `intercept_`?

Comment: @RobertHegner, you can use a few test points, identical in scikit and opencv. If the intercept's sign is wrong, the decision values in prediction will differ by exactly 2*intercept.

Comment: Just as a reference for others: I didn't have to change the sign of `intercept_`, and I didn't have to use the absolute value of `dual_coef_`. It seems to work perfectly well! Thanks again Marc!

Comment: are you sure you need to pass dual_coef and not coef_ as the coefficient of the primal problem? Using the hog.setSVMDetector() i understood i need to pass np.append(coef_, intercept_)