# What are the relevant parameters for reconstructing trained polynomial SVM classifier?

Tags: android, opencv, scikit-learn

I have trained several polynomial SVM classifiers on large data sets using scikit-learn. What I would like to do now is to extract the relevant parameters from the trained models so that I could reconstruct the classifiers using OpenCV. This is useful, for example, for someone who wants to do classification (not training) on Android. I am aware there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832551/import-trained-svm-from-scikit-learn-to-opencv). But that one is related to RBF classifier. My question specifically is, "What are the relevant parameters to extract from a trained model in scikit-learn to reconstruct a **polynomial** SVM classifier in OpenCV?"

What I have done so far is training a polynomial SVM in OpenCV and saving it to a YML file to see what parameters are saved. Here is an example of the file format:

```yaml
    %YAML:1.0
    my_svm: !!opencv-ml-svm
        svm_type: C_SVC
        kernel: { type:POLY, degree:3., gamma:5.0000000000000000e-01, coef0:0. }
        C: 1.
        term_criteria: { epsilon:1.1920928955078125e-07, iterations:1000 }
        var_all: 64
        var_count: 64
        class_count: 10
        class_labels: !!opencv-matrix
            rows: 1
            cols: 10
            dt: i
            data: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
        sv_total: 2416
        support_vectors:
            - [ 7.3965e-02, 1.6008e-01, ..., 6.3552e-02, 1.6624e-01 ]
            #..... <<<many similar entries omitted for brevity>>> .....
            - [ 1.3381e-01, 1.9319e-01, ..., 2.0670e-01, 1.5938e-01, ]
        decision_functions:
            -
                sv_count: 100
                rho: 2.3803118109947000e-01
                alpha: [ 1., 2.0408e-01, 1., 1.3069e-01,..., -1.6480e-01 ]
                index: [ 0, 11, ..., 281, 282 ]
            #..... <<<many similar entries ommited for brevity>>> .....
            -
                sv_count: 249
                rho: 2.6796084003857829e-01
                alpha: [ 1., 6.9822, 4.6517e-01,..., -1., -1., -5.9540e-01 ]
                index: [ 1784, 1785, ..., 2404, 2406 ]
```

I am wondering which of those parameters are relevant and which are not. What I have done next has been extracting the corresponding parameters from a trained model in scikit-learn, replacing those in the above file, and running test classification to see if the reconstructed classifier works. I appreciate anyone who can point out what those parameters are for (e.g., `var_all`, `var_count`, `sv_total`, `dt`, `index`, etc...) and which ones are needed to reconstruct a trained classifier.